# Autostart Firestarter GUI on Boot?

Tags: 10.10, firewall, autostart

Since Firestarter GUI needs Admin rights to start, does it make sense to autostart firestarter on boot and how can i do it?

Comment: ok, just posted the solution as a separate answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addition:

With the following steps firestarter can be autostarted

1. Start a terminal with this command to edit the file /etc/sudoers

   `sudo visudo -s`
2. Add the following line at the end of the code (where username should be replaced by your Ubuntu username)

   `USERNAME ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/firestarter`
3. save the changes and end the editor
4. start these two commands (where username should be replaced by your Ubuntu username)

   `sudo ln -fs ~/.Xauthority /root/.Xauthority`

   `sudo chown USERNAME.root ~/.Xauthority`
5. Now firestarter can start on login without the password prompt
6. Finally you have to add Firestarter to autostart with the following command

   `sudo "firestarter --start-hidden"`

Answer (score 3):

You can't start a GUI app on boot because it needs to be attached to a graphical session, the graphical session is only setup after you login.
You could set it up to start when you login:

System -> Preferences -> Start applications

Add whatever command is required to start it, if it needs admin privilegs you may need to change your /etc/sudoers configuration so that you can start the app with admin privileges without asking for the password.

**Update1:** 
You can check how to edit the sudoers configuration at:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers
There is an example there on how to allow to use the shutdown command without a password.

Comment: sorry, i meant after login. ok, what do i have to add to /etc/sudoers to start without password?

Comment: Added the sudoers info as Update1 in the answer.

Comment: thanks for the help. also updated my question with the step by step solution.